# RestKit: change base URL of RKObjectManager

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, restkit

Is it possible to change base URL of `RKObjectManager` after creation?

I have login box and from nickname I decide which URL for API I should use. If I create `RKObjectManager` after filling nick/password, I can make only single call from RestKit ( https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/restkit/wFNhpCW-URA ). If I create `RKObjectManager` `viewDidLoad` function - I cannot change URL.

Is there same solution to my problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just spent a while figuring out how this can be done in v0.20. From what I can tell, you can't directly change the base URL without getting into the AFNetworking source code. You *can* create a new `HTTPClient` and set it, but I found that this caused even more problems, presumably because RestKit is doing some additional configuration on AFNetworking's `HTTPClient` when you setup the `RKObjectManager`, and by setting the client directly you are missing out on that.

I came up with this solution, which is to create another `RKObjectManager` with the new baseURL and re-add the descriptors. You'll also need to set your serialization and header types again.

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.something.com/api";
RKObjectManager *newManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[newManager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
[newManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
[newManager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].responseDescriptors];
[newManager addRequestDescriptorsFromArray:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].requestDescriptors];
[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:newManager];
```

Related documentation: [Using Multiple Base URLs in RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Using-Multiple-Base-URLs-%28and-Multiple-Object-Managers%29)

Comment: seriously?  you have to re-add all the descriptors just to change the baseUrl ?  EDIT: Ok after reading the documentation I see why, which is because you don't want to change the base URL while requests are still running, etc.  So I guess just implement the above code and move on with it..

Answer (score 6):

Here is the way to change the RestKit `baseURL` after init:

```
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].client.baseURL = [RKURL URLWithString:newBaseUrlString];
```

Notice from RestKit doc:

> Changing the baseURL has the side-effect of causing the requestCache
>   instance to be rebuilt. Caches are maintained a per-host basis.

I use it and it works fine :)

Comment: This works for me in RestKit v0.20:
`[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] setHTTPClient:[AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.somewhere.com"]]];`

Answer (score 2):

Be Careful!

I used the accepted answer for RestKit 2.0 BUT unfortunately this lead to a difficult to debug crash within restkit.  What worked was just encapsulating all the of descriptor creation and other objectmanager settings into a method and calling that with the new object manager object before calling  [RKObjectManager setSharedManager:newManager];

Comment: Yes, the only way is rebuild your RKObjectManager and all relative setups.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a solution for this. RestKit uses base URL internally and it cannot be changed.